# newlib build failed in directory: arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm

Tags: newlib

In the process of building a set of ARM tools. I have used these steps many times before. I have tried the same configure/make in the "newlib-2.5.0.20170922" and "newlib-2.5.0.20170922" directories. Still get the error. I also tried my steps as super-user. No change. In the past building Newlib has always been a problem. Can somebody assist?

```
tar -xf newlib-2.5.0.20170922.tar.gz

cd newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild

../newlib-2.5.0.20170922/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/usr/local --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-nls --disable-werror
make
```

The build proceeds for quite some time until the following error. I examine the only two directories "cpu_init" and "semihv2m".

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss
$ ls
config.log        librdimon.a        rdimon-ftruncate.o  redboot-syscalls.o
config.status     librdpmon.a        rdimon-_kill.o      semihv2m
cpu-init          linux-crt0.o       rdimon-libcfunc.o   syscalls.o
_exit.o           linux-syscalls0.o  rdimon-syscalls.o   trap.o
ftruncate.o       linux-syscalls1.o  rdimon-trap.o       truncate.o
_kill.o           Makefile           rdimon-truncate.o
libcfunc.o        rdimon-crt0.o      rdpmon-crt0.o
libgloss-linux.a  rdimon-_exit.o     redboot-crt0.o

$ ls -l cpu-init
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 3718 Nov 20 06:05 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron  536 Nov 20 06:05 rdimon-aem.o

$ ls -l semihv2m
config.log  config.status  Makefile
$ ls -l semihv2m
total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron   393 Nov 20 06:05 config.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ron ron 32936 Nov 20 06:05 config.status
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron     0 Nov 20 06:05 Makefile

$ cat semihv2m/config.log
## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by config.status, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

CONFIG_FILES    = 
CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
CONFIG_LINKS    = 
CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
$ config.status

config.status:805: error: cannot find input file: `cpu-init/Makefile.in'
```

End of make output:

```
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `cpu-init/Makefile.in'
sed: can't read Makefile: No such file or directory
make[6]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-  2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm/semihv2m'
make[6]: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make[6]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm/semihv2m'
make[5]: *** [../../../../newlib-2.5.0.20170922/libgloss/arm/../multi-build.in:6: multi-do] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:214: all-multi] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:144: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:132: stmp-bsp] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild/arm-none-eabi/libgloss'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9528: all-target-libgloss] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/newlib/newlib-2.5.0.20170922.armbuild'
make: *** [Makefile:879: all] Error 2
```

Comment: I discovered that newlib-2.5.0 does not exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.

It seems to be resolved in the latest version in the [git repository](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git).